# Should index be placed on state column for table?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Example table :

```
promo.code : varchar : unique index
promo.type : tinyint
promo.quantity : int
promo.start : datetime
promo.end : datetime
promo.state : tinyint / bool
```

Sample queries that need to be performed :

```
SELECT * FROM promo WHERE state = 1;
SELECT * FROM promo WHERE code = 'test' AND state = 1;
```

Would it help query performance (standard use cases) to put an index on state column for this example?

Comment: Depends on a small DB optimiser may not use index..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, an index on a column with very few values is not particularly useful.  If `state` is a boolean, then filtering using the index would (typically) return about half the rows in the table.  And that is not very selective.

That said, I can think of three considerations:

1. `state` can also be *part* of an index.  So `(state, code)` would be appropriate for both your queries.
2. `state` as the first column in a *clustered* index can sometimes be useful.
3. If one of the values is quite rare and that is what you want to filter on, then an index *might* be helpful.